# passing objects between forms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

So much as been written about this topic but my problem is a little different than what I can find in the previous threads.  I can pass an object over to a second form but it is not available in all subs of the second form.  I need it to be.   The first code block in frm2 works and the animal name shows but the second code block (cmdSave) does not work - it says animal not declared.  Can someone tell me what I need to change to make the last code block (cmdSave) below work?

**Form 1 code:**

```
    Dim frm2 As New frm2(animal)
    Frm2.Show()
    Me.Close()
```

**frm2 code:**

```
Public Sub New(ByVal animal As Object)
    InitializeComponent()
    Msgbox.show(animal.animalName)
End sub

Private sub cmdSave
    Msgbox.show(animal.animalName)
End sub
```

Comment: Is this `.net`?  Suggest you add a tag.

Comment: excellent suggestion.  I will try to do this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a (private) member in `frm2` holding your passed animal object so that you are able to access it in `cmdSave`.

See the following code, where `m_Animal` is the private member.

*frm2 code:*

```
Public Class Form2
    ...
    Private m_Animal as Object

    Public Sub New(ByVal animal As Object)
        InitializeComponent()
        m_Animal = animal
        Msgbox.show(animal.animalName)
    End sub

    Private sub cmdSave
        Msgbox.show(m_Animal.animalName)
    End sub

...
End Class
```

Comment: @user2076963 ...and if animal is a class, then it should be `Public Sub New(ByVal animal As AnimalClassName)`.  your didnt work because animal went out of `Scope` at the end of Sub New

Comment: This worked perfectly and I'm so appreciative.  I can now make progress again.  And thanks to @Erik for editing my question to make it clearer.  I cannot see how to mark this question as answered and hopefully be able to award you points or somehow reward you for your excellent help.  How can I do this?   Thank you.

Comment: and thank you @Plutonix.  I tried your suggestion but was doing something wrong and couldn't get it to work.  But, the first method works and that's enough.

Comment: I think I did figure out how to mark the question as answered but I do not have enough reputation points to give any thumbs up. I'm bummed about that.