# How do I retain a form's control values when flipping between forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

It takes two forms to be able to enter all the info on a particular transaction.  I want to be able to flip back and forth between these two forms retaining what was entered on each until the 'Save' button is clicked.

I think I should be able to use Form2.Show, Me.Hide and then Form1.Show, Me.Hide.
The first time I go to Form2 it goes thru the Form2 load event (that’s reasonable) but any knowledge of the control contents on Form1 have been lost.   Even though Form1 is hidden (and not closed) the contents of its controls are gone.   Why?

The second time I go to Form2 the load event does not fire because Form2 is hidden and at this point all the Form1 control contents are available.  So, in flipping back and forth between Form1 and Form2 it works as I want it to after I go to Form2 the second time.   But, I need it to work the first time and every time.

For days I’ve been trying to understand this.  I’ve commented out nearly every line of code, stepped thru code, googled till I’m blue in the face (there has been a lot written about this), and I still can’t figure out why this behavior occurs.

Can anyone explain this phenomenon?   Or better yet tell me what I need to do to make this work.

I have this code behind the Form1 button that goes to Form2

```
If Form2 Is Nothing Then
    Dim Form2 As New Form2
End If
Form2.Show()
Me.Hide()
```

And this code behind the Form2 button to return to Form1

```
Form1.Show
Me.Hide
```

Comment: You need an instance of the form object before you can call member functions on it. Where are you creating Form1? And how you getting a reference to it inside of Form2's button click event handler?

Comment: you should not use the class name as the instance name: `Dim f2 As New Form2`, same for Form1.  If `f2` has a reference to `f1` it will work as you want.  With the names as you have them, form1 controls might be "lost" because in one case or the other you are calling the vb default instance.

Comment: I create Form1 in a previous form.  I guess we could call that form Form0.  Cody, I did  not understand your question 'how am I getting a reference.....  I just say 'Form1.Show'.  It was previously loaded and later hidden.

Comment: Plutonix, I will try changing the instance name from the class name.

Comment: I changed the instance name to be something different than the class name.  I said dim f1 as new form1 and f2 as new form2.  But, the button click event to return to f1 (f1.show) got an error.  It said f1 was not declared. I could not get this to work.  @Cody Gray

Comment: each form needs those references if they are going to show each other.    the references needs to be form level scope and not declared in an event or it will only exist in that event

Comment: It's not correct that the form's instance name can't be the same as its class name. "Dim Form1 As Form1" is quite legal.

Comment: no one said it was illegal, just a bad idea especially with forms in VB where `Form1` could refer to either the default instance or an explicitly created reference.

Comment: Using the default instances can be quite lethal.  It goes wrong with any code that runs on another thread.  Like a Task, BackgroundWorker or some code that's using Asynch/Await.  Such code will create a *new* instance of the form class, unseen and undetectable.  Add a constructor to these form classes and set a breakpoint on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all you are probably missing:

```
Class Form1
     Private f2 As Form2       ' this is Form1's reference to the
                               ' form2 instance
```

Later when you click to go to form2, your original code just needs a small tweak:

```
If f2 Is Nothing Then
    f2 = New Form2(Me)             ' set declared variable to new instance   
End If
F2.Show()
Me.Hide()
```

In this case Form1 is passing the reference using [the trick you were shown before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142865/passing-objects-between-forms) using the constructor:

```
Sub New(frm As Form1)         ' this is in Form2 only
   f1 = frm               
End Sub
```

You dont need this in Form1 because he/it is creating his own f2 object reference.

The main problem in your original code, was: `Dim Form2 As New Form2`.  You are creating a new Form2 each time (I suspect that resides in an event or sub). Those new `instances` can't know the control values in the previous instances.  Declaring `F1` or `F2` as shown gives it module/form level `Scope`.

`Dim` declares a variable and its Type. f1 is of Type Form1.  It does not create an object if it is an object variable

`New` creates an instance of an object Type (reference types).  This directly relates to the `Sub New` method in the class.  When you use `New`, `Sub New` is called so anything special that is needed can take place there.  Value types like `Integer` do not need to be created or instanced, only declared.

**Where** you declare (`Dim`) a variable determines its `Scope`.  If you do this in a Sub, the variable or object only exists in that sub.  if you do it at the form/class level, it has Form/Class level scope.

Comment: Plutonix, I couldn't get it to work.  I get an argument not specified error message for the f2 = New Form2 statement.  I'm beginning to think that even with help this problem may be beyond me.  Why would Microsoft not make it easier to flip back and forth between forms?  You could fix my code in about two minutes but me, it's been over a week now and counting.  My brain is mush now and when it recovers I'll be back to try your suggestion again and try to see what I'm doing wrong.  Thank you Plutonix.

Comment: this is very similar to your other similar question.  it sounds like you did not modify `Sub New` to accept a form argument as shown in the answer (see sub new). It isnt hard, but there are some concepts you need to grasp.  I'll edit in a bit, but it sounds like you applied only part of the answer.  Maybe edit your post so we can see what you did.

Comment: It is similar.  In the other question I wanted to use variables carried over to a second form in various subs of the second form.  That little trick I was shown worked well.  In this case I want to return to the first form and have the content that was entered show up.  And everything works perfectly and just as one would want it to for all trips back and forth between forms after the first trip.  But, the first trip, nada.

Comment: I didn't mean to stop there on the last comment.  I should not have pressed enter.

Comment: they are the same in principle - in this case, you need to pass/store and object (form) reference instead of a simple variable.  you cant create a New form2 each time and expect it to know what was on the previous one.  I added some explanation to the answer.

Comment: I'm trying again now.

Comment: Here is my mental block.  If I create Form1 and later hide it how does it lose the content entered in it's controls (text boxes)?  I can understand that if I dimmed the form as new again then yes, I would expect things to be gone. But just hiding it and later only showing it?  It seems that the content should still be there.

Comment: A workaround would be to store all the input into a global object and every time the form appears repopulate the controls from the object.  This shouldn't be necessary though.  I need to read and try to understand all that you've explained to me.

Comment: My latest attempt failed by the way.  I'll have to later show you my exact code.

Comment: it very much depends on WHERE and HOW you create that form1 object.  For **certain**, form2 needs to be given a reference to the form1 object if you want the SAME form1 with the same control content to be retained.  the terrible names make it more confusing as well.  Finally, if you dont need Form2 to retain its control values, you could do ShowDialog so you just go back to the same Form1 afterwards...but that is not what you asked.

Comment: Plutonix, it seems SO is upset about the numerous comments.  I'll see if there is such a thing as an email message.  If not then I'll keep trying without more comments.  And I'll mark you answer as the solution. I know it will work if only I can implement it properly.  Thanks so much for all of your help.

Comment: its not upset, it just suggests chat automatically after X messages between the same 2 IDs.  I perhaps should have been clearer with Do this in Form1 (...) do this in form2 (...) but the solution is **very** much the same as the other answer just with form objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this. Display the 2 forms modally using the ShowDialog method.

In each form, create a property (call it "OtherForm") which points to an instance of the other form.

Continue the loop by setting the DialogResult of either form to Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes

Exit the loop by setting the DialogResult of either form to Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No

This will execute each forms load event each time it is displayed.

So call this from a button click event procedure on your so-called Form0.

```
Dim Form1 As New Form1
Dim Form2 As New Form2
Dim sFormToShow As String = "Form1"

Form1.OtherForm = Form2
Form1.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes

Form2.OtherForm = Form1
Form2.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes

Do

    If sFormToShow = "Form1" Then
        Form1.ShowDialog()
    ElseIf sFormToShow = "Form2" Then
        Form2.ShowDialog()
    End If

    sFormToShow = IIf(sFormToShow = "Form1", "Form2", "Form1")

Loop While Form1.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes AndAlso Form2.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
```

Add this property to Form1:

```
Private _myOtherForm As Form2

Public Property OtherForm() As Form2
    Get
        Return _myOtherForm
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Form2)
        _myOtherForm = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Add this property to Form2:

```
Private _myOtherForm As Form1

Public Property OtherForm() As Form1
    Get
        Return _myOtherForm
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Form1)
        _myOtherForm = value
    End Set
End Property
```

From each form, you will then be able to access all of the public properties and methods of the other form using the _myOtherForm variable.

If you were to call this from Form1, it will display the text in TextBox1 in Form2 and vice-versa:

```
MessageBox.Show(_myOtherForm.TextBox1.Text)
```

To close the current form, continue the loop and open the other form, add this to a button click event procedure:

```
Private Sub btnShowOtherForm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShowOtherForm.Click
    Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

To close the current form, exit the loop and to cease showing any further forms, add this to a button click event procedure:

```
Private Sub btnStopShowingForms_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStopShowingForms.Click
    Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

These two procedures need to be added to each form.

Comment: GJ, thanks for all your help on this.  Right now it looks like the solution Plutonix gives is simpler and more inline with what I already have.  But, I haven't tried it yet and don't know if I can get it to work. If not then I will try your solution.  At any rate I'll be back with a report later.  Thank you.  @Plutonix